# Website from login page i want to direct to the main page?

Tags: php, html, authentication, program-entry-point

I have a login page and whenever I press the login button I want to lead me to the main page. As you see now I  have the login page in the navigation bar. I want to remove the login page from there. How can I redirect from login to main page? Thanks in advance!!!

login.php

```
  <html>
    <head><h1>Login Page</h1>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    </head>
      <center>

           <form action = "login.php" method = "POST">

             Username: <input type="text" name="username"> <br /><br/>
             Password: <input type="password" name="password"> <br /><br/>

            <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">


           </form>

      </center>

</body>
</html>

    <?php

       require('connect.php');

       $username = @$_POST['username'];
       $password = @$_POST['password'];

   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
   if($username && $password)
   {
           $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password= '".$password."'");
           $rows = mysql_num_rows($check);


         if(mysql_num_rows($check)!=0)
         {
             echo "Successful login.";
         }
         else
         {
            echo "Couldn't find username.";

         }
      }
      else
      {
         echo "Please fill all the fields.";
      }
   }
 ?>

  e-Statistics.htm
         <html>
          <head>
                 <title>e-Statistics</title>
           <style>
           .body{
              margin: 0;

            }

           .nav{
             width: 115%;
             height:40px;
             background:black;
             text-align:center;
           }
          .nav ul{
             width: 800px;
             margin:0 auto;
             padding:0;
             }
            .nav ul li{
               list-style: none;

            }
           .nav ul li a{
               float: left;
               text-decoration:none;
               display:block;
               padding:10px 40px;
               color:#ff9933 ;
               border-right:1px solid #ccc;
             }
            .nav ul li a:hover{
                color:white;

            }
           </style>
      </head>
    <body>

       <div class="nav">
         <ul>
               <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
               <li><a href="">Principal</a></li>
               <li><a href="">Academic Director</a></li>
               <li><a href="">Lecturer</a></li>

         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: There's a gaping SQL injection vulnerability in this code. Also, don't use  `mysql_*` functions, they've been deprecated since PHP 5.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First move your PHP code to the start of the file, secondly, use header("location: /main.php"); exit(); to redirect after a successful login

```
<?php

       $error = '';

       require('connect.php');

       $username = @$_POST['username'];
       $password = @$_POST['password'];

   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
   if($username && $password)
   {
           $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password= '".$password."'");
           $rows = mysql_num_rows($check);


         if(mysql_num_rows($check)!=0)
         {
             header("location: /main.php");
             exit();
         }
         else
         {
            $error = "Couldn't find username.";

         }
      }
      else
      {
         echo "Please fill all the fields.";
      }
   }
 ?>
<html>
    <head><h1>Login Page</h1>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    </head>
      <center>

           <?php echo $error; ?>

           <form action = "login.php" method = "POST">

             Username: <input type="text" name="username"> <br /><br/>
             Password: <input type="password" name="password"> <br /><br/>

            <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">


           </form>

      </center>

</body>
</html>
```

You need to do the PHP processing first, because header("location:... will not work if content has already been sent.

Answer (score 0):

In the login page, after you did the operations to log in the user, you can use `header()` function:

```
header("Location: index.php")
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this...

```
if(mysql_num_rows($check) > 0)
         {
            header("Location: index.php");
         }
```

and NOTE to always use `mysql_real_escape_string` while you are creating a login page.. it avoids the SQL injection.